# Cocos2d-x 3.2 Error - Change Arrays to Vectors?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am getting an error with the following code because I am using arrays instead of vectors. What would be the best way to write this code using vectors?

```
CCAnimate* createAnimate(int frameCount, float duration, const char* imageName)
{
   CCArray * spritesArray = CCArray::create();

   for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {

      CCString *spritePath = CCString::createWithFormat("%s%i.png",imageName,i);
      CCSprite *sprite = CCSprite::create(spritePath->getCString());
      spritesArray->addObject(sprite);

   }

   CCArray *animationFrames = CCArray::create();

   for (int i = 0; i < spritesArray->count(); i++) {

      CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite*)spritesArray->objectAtIndex(i);
      CCSpriteFrame *frame = sprite->displayFrame();
      animationFrames->addObject(frame);

   }

   CCAnimation* animation =  CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(animationFrames,duration);
   CCAnimate* animate= CCAnimate::create(animation);

   return animate;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vector<SpriteFrame*> VillanspriteFrames(frameCount);
    for (int i = 1; i <= frameCount; i++) {
    char fileName[128] = { 0 };
    sprintf(fileName, "imageName%d.png", i);

    auto frames = spriteCache->getSpriteFrameByName(fileName);
    VillanspriteFrames.pushBack(frames);
}

auto swordRun = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(VillanspriteFrames,
        duration);
swordRun->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true);
auto animate = Animate::create(swordRun);
return animate;
```

To use this code u have to use a .plist file using Texture packer, pack all the files in it using desired names.
Add a Texture file in your Init Method like...

```
SpriteFrameCache *spriteCachespriteCache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
spriteCache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("FightAnim.plist", "FightAnim.png");
```

SpriteFrameCache is a singleton object.
Hope this helps You.